# How can I write my cat's name, TK-421, in Chinese?

Tags: translation, characters

TK-421 (pronounced Teekay four two one) is the serial number of a character in a science fiction movie (and also my charming cat). What would be the most natural way to write this down?

TK-四二一?

TK-四百二十一?

Should anything be done with the letters?

Comment: T can correspond with any [ti] pinyin and K corresponds with any [kei] pinyin, you could theoretically come up with something like: 踢剋-四二一

Comment: The Chinese translation usually comes out to something like: 编号Tk421

Comment: You want to write it down instead of read it out? then TK-412 is OK. No Chinese character is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TK-421, as a serial number, is ok in Chinese. But pronounce differently from English.